# php method to read xlsx file without PHPExcel

Tags: excel, yii

is their any method or class or script to read xlsx file into database as i tried with phpexcel but that is very heavy and take time to load and some time i need to import data count like 300000 so its harder for phpexcel to read then store in database. so can you tel me any working script alternate for xlsx file to read.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using codeplex library, you have multiple other libraries which are lightweight. few are:

http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

Comment: both are not working. first one is not working with xlsx file and second has many bugs even after resolve them its just keep loading nothing happening